# Как получить имя принтера (который установлен по умолчанию)

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.

Работаю с библиотекой Aspose.Cells, там для печати excel документа необходимо указать 2 параметра, имя принтера и имя документа, если со вторым все понятно - то первый вызывает затруднение.

Пример кода:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(path_);

        Worksheet worksheet;

        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

        Aspose.Cells.Rendering.ImageOrPrintOptions options = new Aspose.Cells.Rendering.ImageOrPrintOptions();

        options.PrintingPage = PrintingPageType.Default;

        SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(worksheet, options);

        sr.ToPrinter("Имя принтера", "Имя документа");
```

p.s. принтер сетевой.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

private static string GetDefaultPrinterName()
{
    String[] printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < printers.Length; i++)
        if (new PrinterSettings() { PrinterName = printers[i] }.IsDefaultPrinter)
            return printers[i];
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, Ваш пример у меня выдал ошибку в Cast<string>, переписал его немного.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;

private static string GetDefaultPrinterName()
        {
            string default_printer = "";

            foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                if (new PrinterSettings() { PrinterName = printer }.IsDefaultPrinter)
                {
                    default_printer = printer;
                }
                else
                {
                    default_printer = null;
                }
            }

            return default_printer;
        }
```

Comment: Ошибка видимо обусловлена отсутствием у Вас

    using System.Linq;

Comment: Абсолютно верно, спасибо.